# One cronjob for multiple subdomains

Tags: php, cron, include

I have set up a cronjob 'cron_parent.php' in my root directory. It works like this:

1. Check which customer folders exist (ie. subdomains)
2. Using `foreach()`, include the cron_child.php for each relevant subdomain
3. The actual work is done in each subdomain's cron_child.php.

All subdomains contain identical php files and functions. So of course, I ran into trouble when using this on more than one subdomain, because

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot redeclare fserror() (previously declared in
/home/***hidden***/public_html/demo/dbconfig.php:28) 
in <b>/home/***hidden***/public_html/dev/dbconfig.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
```

I realize that `include()` is probably not the right option here. Is there a way to run the cron_child.php's 'detached' from cron_parent.php?

Edit: Added code from cron_parent.php:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Oslo");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$directories = glob($root . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach($directories as $path)
{
  if(is_file("$path/cron_child.php"))
  {
    include("$path/cron_child.php");
  }
}
```

For testing purposes, cron_child.php only contains this right now:

```
<?php
include "functions.php";
return false;
```

Comment: Show your code!  There also `require_once` and `include_once`. But my guess you need to look at design patterns ;).

Comment: Yes you can! You can start a new php process with `exec('php /path/to/script.php')` which will then run as a child process.

Comment: @E_p you're probably right about having a look at design patterns. I could of course set up a cronjob for each of my subdomains, but I thought it would be easier to just have a parent php file executing the cron_child in each subdomain. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: @JensV I tried but the server ran out of memory on the first iteration of cron_child.php. I don't understand why, though, because when I run the same file from the browser it finishes in 1-2 seconds.

Comment: @aanders77 could you post your code? Couldn't imagine that happen unless you have some kind of infinite loop.

Comment: @JensV wrong person ;)

Comment: @JensV Updated the question with code. If I `print_f($directories)` it returns the 5 directories that it should.

Comment: @aanders77 Interesting, so if you replace `include...` with `exec("php $path/cron_child.php");` it will run out of memory? Or what does the output say exactly? You can also use `passthru` instead of exec to have the full output of each script.

Comment: @aanders77 Also btw. you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Question is still open. Are those different jobs or same job different configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php), [Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/classobj.examples.php)

Something like that should work(just structure):

```
// main.php
<?php

    require_once('jobHandler.php');

    foreach (new DirectoryIterator('your/folder') as $fileInfo) {
        // If it is not folder skip;
        if($fileInfo->isDot() || ! $file->isDir) continue;

        $worker = new jobHandler($folderToProcess);
        $worker->run();
    }


// jobHandler.php    
<?php

    class jobHandler
    {
        public function __construct($folder)
        {
            // validation here
        }

        public function run()
        {
            echo $this->folder . PHP_EOL;
            // Do your work here.
        }

        private $folder = null;        
    }
```

And you can store job configuration in the customer folders.

Comment: I don't think that this is the source of the issue. Using glob to list the directories works just as well.

Comment: @JensV The problem is `includes`. I showed the way to avoid inclusion of logic multiple times.

Comment: oh yeah, if the case is that you have to do the same work in every subdirectory, an approach like this is way smarter.

Comment: That is exactly the case! I will give this a try tomorrow and get back to you :)

Comment: @E_p, quick question. Could I use `include $this->folder . "/includedfile.php"` where you have commented //Do your work here? :p

Comment: @aanders77 In theory yes. But you should not use include in like that as it'll end up just like your code. What is inside of files you try to include?

Comment: @aanders77 See how I did `require_once` and than used instance of an object(`new jobHandler`). That is a way better option!